# Scala sortWith problems

Tags: scala, sorting

```
val population: List[Animal] = for (animal <- animals) yield {
    val value: T = incubator(animal.genes)
    new Animal(animal.genes, costFunction(value))
  }
  for (x<-population){
    println(x.cost + " " + x.genes)
  }

  println("sorted:")

  val orderedAnimals: List[Animal] = population.sortWith(_.cost < _.cost)
  for (i<-orderedAnimals){
    println(i.cost + " " + i.genes)
  }
  println("-------------------")
  println()
```

So I have a list of animal objects (animal has two attributes; genes: List[Double] and cost: Double. I'm trying to sort them in order of their cost value, lowest cost->highest cost, but I'm running into an error.

Here's whats being printed when I run the program, instead of sorting by the cost value, it's sorting by the absolute value of the first double in the genes list. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Can you give us an [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can debug it.

Comment: It's hard to make an explicit MCVE for this, but basically in the above code: animals is a list of 4 animals each with 3 genes each, genes are lists of doubles and each gene is a double. The genes are randomly assigned values in the range(-100,100). "incubator" is a method that takes a list of doubles (genes) and returns an object. This object is used by the method "cost", cost takes an object of type T and returns a cost. This cost is then used to create a new animal object.

Comment: its a program for a genetic algorithm

Comment: I think what you want here is `sortBy(_.cost)`

Comment: What is the type of `Animal.cost`? If it's a `Double`, your code ought to work. However, if it's a reference to a class instance, and has a `toString` method that merely prints a value, then you're sorting the animals by the addresses of those instances instead.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr Your program is correct. You are neglecting the exponent of in scientific notation.

Since the data we could use to try to show to you was in a image I went ahead and "OCR-ed" it. And made this:

```
scala> List(6.434636141757189E8, 6.048938092998665E9, 4.08466301816955E9, 2.038557228389767E10).sorted // copied from the first block (before "sorted")
res1: List[Double] = List(6.434636141757189E8, 4.08466301816955E9, 6.048938092998665E9, 2.038557228389767E10)

scala> List(6.434636141757189E8, 4.08466301816955E9, 6.048938092998665E9, 2.038557228389767E10) // copied from the 2nd block (after "sorted:")
res2: List[Double] = List(6.434636141757189E8, 4.08466301816955E9, 6.048938092998665E9, 2.038557228389767E10)
```

And to confirm our assumptions we can do a small experiment:

```
scala> List(6.434636141757189E8, 6.048938092998665E9, 4.08466301816955E9,
 2.038557228389767E10).sorted.sliding(2)
  .toList.collect{ case List(small, big) => small < big } // (*)
res7: List[Boolean] = List(true, true, true)
```

QED :)

(*) `sliding(2)`:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4).sliding(2).toList
res8: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(3, 4))
```